# how to get the ViewModel from the View to the Controller without submitting the form?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 app using Razor.

One of the view displays  a form. 
I would like one of this form's button to call the controller via ajax and pass him the current ViewModel without submitting the form.

Not sure if I am clear.
I know how to get the ViewModel back from the View to the Controller when submitting the form.
But in this case, I don t want to submit the form, but I need to pass the ViewModel.

Is this possible?

I suppose I could pass to Ajax the form serialization via Jquery this way:

```
$("Formid").serialize()
```

But maybe Razor is able to pass the ViewModel directly?

Thx in advance

Comment: There is no "getting the model from the view". Ultimately your view is plain old html. The model is built from the request data. So then the question is how you can get the request data to bind to a model.

Comment: I was talking about strongly typed views where you do bind the view to an instance of your ViewModel:
@model MyViewModelclass;

Comment: Binding a model to your view is a server-side trick. The client still receives just a plain old html page. There is no model on the client side, just html. When the client submits a request to the server some magic happens to that request to build the model again.